# How to prove: $ \int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{\frac{x+a}{x}} dx = a\big\{ \sqrt{2}+ln(1+\sqrt{2}) \big\} \ ?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm asked to prove this. I've succeeded (kind of). I made the substitutions $$x=a\ sinh^2(z), @\ x=0:z=0, @\ x=a:z=0.8814, dx=2a\sinh(z)cosh(z)$$
and i found: $a\int_{0}^{0.8814} cosh(2z) +1 dz  = a\ 2.2957$. $\big[a(\sqrt{2}+ln(1+\sqrt{2}))=a\ 2.29558\big]$

But, with my version there were no natural logarithms occurring, or square roots in the end. How can i solve it, in order to find: $a\Big\{ \sqrt{2}+ln(1+\sqrt{2}) \Big\}$?

I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\log$ doesn't occur because you make a decimal approximation when substituting... Anyway, probably one can carry this out manually with more familiar functions using the substitution $x = a \tan^2 \theta$.

Comment: Inverse hyperbolic sine is $\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$, so that is probably where your $\log$ should come from.

Comment: @Travis i've tried this substitution but $ \int sec^3(θ)dθ $ is appearing, making it very messy.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra Yes, $\int \sec^3 \theta \,d\theta$ is a classic example of a tricky but elementary integral, enough so that it has its own Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed . Anyway, we can't avoid this altogether with this integral, as the solution itself is a little involved (entailing both a logarithm and two radicals). Anyway, using a hyperbolic substitution here simply pushes the complication around laterally (in this case to the expression of the relevant inverse hyperbolic function as a composition of algebraic and logarithmic functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=x+\frac{a}{2}$

\begin{align}
\int_0^a\sqrt{\frac{x+a}{x}}\,dx&=\int_{0}^{a}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+ax}}{x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\frac{a^2}{4}}}{x}\,dx\\
\end{align}

Now, let $x+\frac{a}{2}=\frac{a}{2}\sec t$, then
\begin{align}
\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\frac{a^2}{4}}}{x}\,dx&=\int_{0}^{\sec^{-1}3}\frac{\frac{a}{2}\tan t}{\frac{a}{2}\sec t-\frac{a}{2}}\frac{a}{2}\sec t\tan t\,dt\\[10pt]
&=\frac{a}{2}\int_{0}^{\sec^{-1}3}\frac{(\sec t+1)\tan t}{(\sec t+1)(\sec t - 1)}\sec t\tan t\,dt\\[10pt]
&=\frac{a}{2}\int_{0}^{\sec^{-1}3}(\sec t+1)\sec t\,dt\\[10pt]
&=\frac{a}{2}\left[\tan t+\ln\left(\sec t+\tan t\right)\right]_0^{\sec^{-1}3}\\
&=\frac{a}{2}\left[\sqrt{3^2-1}-0+\ln\left(3+\sqrt{3^2-1}\right)-\ln(0+1)\right]\\
&=a\left[\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)\right]
\end{align}

Notice
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)=\ln\left(\sqrt{3+2\sqrt 2}\right)=\ln (1+\sqrt{2})$$

Then,
$$\int_0^a\sqrt{\frac{x+a}{x}}\,dx=\boxed{\color{blue}{a\{\sqrt{2}+\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\}}}$$

Comment: Very elegant. My only question is why $ln(\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2} }) = ln(1+\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: Never mind, i got it. Thank you very much.